# Use dropdown menu choice in Excel VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet containing names of products and their categories. In a separate sheet I created a drop down menu of categories and right by the side of that drop down I inserted a "go" button.

I want if I select Category 1 from the drop down menu and then click go, it should open a sheet containing products that are of category 1 only.

I was able to do it by assigning a macro. But the problem occurred when after this I selected category 2 and pressed the button it showed me products of 1 (of course I assigned that).

How do I make it dynamic? I want the button to redirect me with respect to the option I chose in drop down menu.

Comment: Is the dropdown menu a data validation and what cell is it in?

Answer (score 1):

Change the range to what cell you require.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    Dim r As String
    r = Range("A1")
    Sheets(r).Select
End Sub
```